# Read whole data with Golang net.Conn.Read

Tags: go

So I'm building a network app in Go and I've seen that `Conn.Read` reads into a limited byte array, which I had created with `make([]byte, 2048)` and now the **problem** is that I don't know the exact length of the content, so it could be too much or not enough.
My question is how can I just read the exact amount of data. I think I have to use `bufio`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Show us what kind of data you're trying to read, otherwise it's just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It highly depends on what you're trying to do, and what kind of data you're expecting, for example if you just want to read until the EOF you could use something like this:

```
func main() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "google.com:80")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("dial error:", err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    fmt.Fprintf(conn, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")

    buf := make([]byte, 0, 4096) // big buffer
    tmp := make([]byte, 256)     // using small tmo buffer for demonstrating
    for {
        n, err := conn.Read(tmp)
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                fmt.Println("read error:", err)
            }
            break
        }
        //fmt.Println("got", n, "bytes.")
        buf = append(buf, tmp[:n]...)

    }
    fmt.Println("total size:", len(buf))
    //fmt.Println(string(buf))
}
```

//edit: for completeness sake and @fabrizioM's great suggestion, which completely skipped my mind:

```
func main() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "google.com:80")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("dial error:", err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    fmt.Fprintf(conn, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    io.Copy(&buf, conn)
    fmt.Println("total size:", buf.Len())
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've thought about this (Python socket.recv), but I'm kind of a noob in Go, so didn't know how to implement it.

Comment: If you want to copy all the content you could also use io.Copy(conn, NewBuffer)

Comment: My understanding is that conn.Read(buf) is blocking and will read either the full length of the buffer, if possible, or up to the point of an EOF at which point n will be different than cap(buf) - but possibly the same as len(buf), if it was declared with 3 args. Is that correct?

Comment: The answer from vially seems superior, is there any benefit to adopting one of your two approaches?

Comment: Nope, his approach is correct and preferred, only reason you would use mine is if you want to work on a buffer rather than the slice.

Comment: Your read loop might not print out the last few bytes if it gets `io.EOF` together with a non-zero `n`. According to the documentation of `io.Reader`, this could happen

Comment: I prefer your first approach with the 'tmp' buffer where you have complete control of what's going on. It would allow you to handle any size of input coming through the connection without running the risk of "out of memory" errors, for example.

Answer (score 39):

You can use the [`ioutil.ReadAll`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) function:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net"
)

func whois(domain, server string) ([]byte, error) {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", server+":43")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    fmt.Fprintf(conn, "%s\r\n", domain)
    return ioutil.ReadAll(conn)
}
```

Comment: This function just seems to hang for me, never get any response

Comment: @BrianLeishman you mean the `whois` function I wrote as an example or the `ioutil.ReadAll` function? If it's the latter, it most probably means that the `Reader` you are passing in neither reaches EOF nor gets an error.

Comment: Both, I found out what it was in my specific situation though, I was trying to read all of the response on an IMAP connection, but the response isn't really finished until you close it yourself so it "hung" (later I correctly read lines until I got the final response and then stopped reading more lines), but my pasting this into a blank, new .go file just never returned any results

Answer (score 8):

You can read data something like this:

```
// import net/textproto
import ("net/textproto", ...)

....

reader := bufio.NewReader(Conn)
tp := textproto.NewReader(reader)

defer Conn.Close()

for {
    // read one line (ended with \n or \r\n)
    line, _ := tp.ReadLine()
    // do something with data here, concat, handle and etc... 
}
....
```

Comment: Isn't there a more efficient way to do this? And also, is there a way in which I don't have to use an infinite loop?

Comment: Why do I need endless for loop to read only one line?