# O_NONBLOCK SOCK_STREAM limited to 8192

Tags: c, sockets, go

I'm writing from c program into a `SOCK_STREAM` of a Unix Domain Socket that is being listened from a go program, using `net.Listen("unix", sockname)`. When I set the socket to `O_NONBLOCK` using `fcntl()`, I see that the C program writes only 8192 bytes in the first write. After it fails, I monitor and write back the remaining data, but the read data on my server is not valid in this case.

When I do not use `O_NONBLOCK`, then the whole of 8762 bytes are written in a single write and everything works as expected.

**C Client Socket Connection**

```
    if ( (fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        return;
    }
   int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
   flags = flags|O_NONBLOCK;
   fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags);
   ...
    if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
        return;
    }
```

**C Client Writing**

```
        while (written < to_write) {
            int result;
            if ((result = write(fd, &buffer[written], to_write - written)) < 0) {
                if (errno == EINTR) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (errno == EAGAIN) {
                    struct pollfd pfd = { .fd = fd, .events = POLLOUT };
                    poll_count++;
                    if (poll_count > 3) {
                        goto end;
                    }
                    if ((poll(&pfd, 1, -1) <= 0) && (errno != EAGAIN)) {
                        goto end;
                    }
                    continue;
                }
end:
                return written ? written : result;
            }
            written += result;
            buffer += result;
        }
```

**Go Server Reading**

```
buf := make([]byte, 0, count)
var tmpsize int32
for {
    if count <= 0 {
        break
    }

    if count > 100 {
        tmpsize = 100
    } else {
        tmpsize = count
    }

    tmp := make([]byte, tmpsize)
    nr, err = conn.Read(tmp)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    buf = append(buf, tmp[:nr]...)
    count = count - int32(nr)
}
```

What am I missing here. I'm running it on OSX. I also tried setting the `SO_SNDBUF` in the Go Server to 10000, but it does not help

```
err = syscall.SetsockoptInt(int(fd.Fd()), syscall.SOL_SOCKET, syscall.SO_SNDBUF, 10000)
if err != nil {
    return
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily related, but you don't need to allocate a new buffer for every read,. You do need to check `nr` before you check for `io.EOF`. Also setting `SO_SNDBUF` on the Go connection isn't going to effect the receive buffer. Note that getting the fd from the Go connection dup'ed the file descriptor and put in into blocking mode.

Comment: You need to drop the `goto` statements or improve the logic.  When you get `EAGAIN` your code will rapidly spin through three of them.  You also never reset `poll_count`.

Comment: And `write()` returns `ssize_t`, **not** `int`.

Comment: @JimB the client does not close the socket after sending the data. Therefore, I'm sending an initial count first and then sending the data from the client to the server. So when I allocate a huge []byte, then the `conn.Read` blocks, till EOF is received and EOF won't be received, as the socket won't be closed. Is other thoughts on this? Regarding `SO_SNDBUF`, I removed it now.

Comment: in 'C client writing' this statement: `buffer += result;` should NOT be there.  It causes blocks of data to be skipped during this statement: `if ((result = write(fd, &buffer[written], to_write - written)) < 0) {`

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have set the poll timeout to -1, so that I really wait in the poll till the socket becomes available. But my original code was, as you have said, to have timeout as 0 and it did spin rapidly between these three and was thrown out. The `poll_count` is reset above the while loop, that is missing from what I pasted here.

Comment: @user3629249 Awesome. That was the problem... ah!! I first added it at the end and then I forgot and added it again at the top. Thanks buddy!

Comment: @JAamish: you re-allocate `tmp` on every loop - you don't need to do that. You could allocate it once, or just read directly into `buf`. I'm just commenting on the correctness, since you _must_ check `nr` before you check the error; that's simply how using an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) is documented.

Comment: @JimB I'm must check nr for > 0, you mean

Comment: @JAamish: yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is read the data straight into a `bytes.Buffer` similar to the answer listed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24343240/8092543

https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy

The beauty of the `io.Copy` is that it consumes a Writer + Reader interface, which are satisfied nicely but your `bytes.Buffer` (io.Writer) and your `conn.Read` (io.Reader). Replace your entire block with something like...

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
count, err := io.Copy(buf, conn)
if err != nil { 
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("error during conn read: %v", err)
}

return buf.Bytes(), nil
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour. A non-blocking write can only transfer as much data as will fit into the socket send buffer. If you get a short count, you need to either loop or select on writability and retry. A blocking write on the other hand always transfers the entire data.

Setting the send buffer size may not do anything on Unix domain sockets.