# TCP Handler is blocking on connection.Read()

Tags: go, byte, buffer

I'm following this guide:

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmfYeDhGH9bZzihBUDEQbCbTc5k5FZKURMUoUvfmc27BwL/socket/tcp_sockets.html

Everything is implemented the same, as the final example. My handler is implemented differently because I can expect messages between 2-128 bytes sent to my server. This code appears to block and never exit my the loop. What could I do better with my reader setup?

```
func Handle(c net.Conn, s *stack.Stack) {
        defer c.Close()
        fmt.Printf("Serving %s\n", c.RemoteAddr().String())

        buf := make([]byte, 0, 256)
        for {
                tmp := make([]byte, 8)
                n, err := c.Read(tmp[0:])
                if err != nil {
                        if err == io.EOF {
                                fmt.Println("does this happen")
                                break
                        }
                        return
                }

                buf = append(buf, tmp[:n]...)
        }

  // does not print
  fmt.Printf("buff ************%v", buf) 
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339660/read-whole-data-with-golang-net-conn-read

Comment: `Handle` reads data until EOF (the peer closes write on the connection) or error.  Does the peer close write on the connection?   `Handle` should collect data returned from `c.Read` before processing the error.  Better yet, replace the guts of the function with a call to [ioutil.ReadAll](https://godoc.org/io/ioutil#ReadAll).